# list of ints to array in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of ints called `MyList`. In javascript, when we call `toString` on an array of numbers, it converts it into a string with each number separated with commas; I'm looking to do the same with in C#.

I tried calling `.ToString`() to the list but it's returning the type of the list. I'm thinking of a loop that iterates over the list and add each element to a stringbuilder, along with the comma, and then .ToString() the stringbuilder.

Is that the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx):

```
string result = string.Join(",", MyList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) method to "implode" the array with a separator.

e.g.:

```
String.Join(",", MyList);
```

Answer (score 2):

try use this code :

```
 List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
            MyList.Add(1);
            MyList.Add(2);
            MyList.Add(3);
            MyList.Add(4);
            MyList.Add(5);
            MyList.Add(6);

            var m = string.Join(",", MyList);

            MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
```